# PHP mySQL Htaccess pretty links

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

There is a rewrite rule ensuring that all URL's head to index.php and maintain a 'pretty format'.

I still need to get information from them to work out what page to send the user.

Say there is a Url

```
http://localhost/telephones/nokia
```

I need to find out the SQL table ('telephone') and the make ('nokia')

How do I do that.

UPDATE

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /index.php?table=$1&make=$2 [NC]
```

(in .htaccess)

```
$table = $_GET['table']; $make = $_GET['make'];
$CONsiteurl = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE name = $make");
```

So we can bring up the page now by typing in `http://localhost/?make=nokia&table=telephones` but cannot get to it by typing in `http://localhost/telephones/nokia`

Why

Comment: What is the current rewrite rule?

Comment: The rewrite rule sends everything to index.php from which I've tried an explode on the slashes and foreach on the results. Not very good or flexible.

Comment: Are you sure your `.htaccess` file is actually being used? To make sure, just add a `Deny from all` clause to it and see if you get a 403.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have mod_rewrite setup you can put something like this in you .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /index.php?table=$1&make=$2 [NC]
```

Then you can access the values from php using $_GET('table') etc.

Comment: This just says page not found. I have tried it but I do not understand how it is supposed to work. I have made a page called localhost/pages/sample-page. I can get to it by typing in localhost?table=pages&make=sample-page but not by typing in the 'pretty url'

Comment: http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php or some other tutorial you can find at at a search engine near you.

Comment: Shown you my entire process in question. Exactly as in documentation but not working. Please help